# SupportMapFragment is null when I implement it with Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I would kindly ask you for any help, I have been breaking my head with this issue for two days now, and I can't proceed until I solve this :/

Well, I'm trying to implement GoogleMap with Navigation Drawer, and I kinda managed to do that, but it doesn't work very well.

Here are my classes and xml-s, keep in mind that most of them is autogenerated.

MapFragment.java :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MapFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MapFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters


    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private GoogleMap gMap;
    private Double lat, lng;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MapFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MapFragment newInstance() {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("Map", "map");
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }*/

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


/*
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        MapFragment f = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (f != null)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
*/

    public void setUpMapIfNeeded(){

        try {
            if (gMap == null)
                gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error with retrieving map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (gMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }

    }
    public void setUpMap() {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Setting up map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


}
```

fragment_map.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements MapFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,StatsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();



        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();



            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                try {
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, MapFragment.newInstance()).commit();
                    break;
                    }
                catch (NullPointerException e) {Toast.makeText(this,"Error retrieving map fragment",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}
                }



                case 1: {
                    mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                     fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, StatsFragment.newInstance())
                        .commit();
                    break;
                }
            }




    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {
            openHelpDialog();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void openHelpDialog(){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("About")
                .setMessage("Pocket Buddy V1.0 \nAuthor : Milos Matic")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aaaaaaaaaaa" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="I'm a using correct key"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.shomi.pocketbuddy.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Well, main problem is that I'm not getting GoogleMap object every time I switch to MapFragment, I managed to bypass it with try-catch block and it works, but it won't let me set any preferences on my map.

For example setUpMap() is never called.

I tried re arranging my code several times, and it's still the same.

I want to be able to save fragments state and then to switch freely without loosing my data (I want to draw on my map based on movement, so can't draw it every time from scratch) but I'm not able to do that until I solve this.

I think that problems is that Gmap object is not ready fast enough as rest of app, but I don't know how to counter that :/

My Device is Nexus 5, running Android 5.0

Every bit of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Use

```
gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```